# Work around for a python regex bug^H^H^H...ahem...misfeature needed

Tags: python, regex

I have some code that is generating a regular expression.  Well the following expression in fact:

```
^(?:\s*((exclude|include|hide|show|protect|risk|dir-merge|merge)),\s*((-|+|H|S|P|R|:|.))\s*(\S+)|\s*,?\s*((-|+|H|S|P|R|:|.))\s*(\S+)|\s*((exclude|include|hide|show|protect|risk|dir-merge|merge))\s*(\S+))$
```

It looks complicated, but its essentially meant to match the following, among others, lines in a file:

```
dir-merge, :    /some/file
   merge,   . /some/other/file
. /another/file
 , :    /yet/another/file
```

Hence the `\s*` matches that are causing the Python regex compilation errors.

Is there a better way to match these combinations in a single expression without matching blocks of `nothing`?

*Answered*

In addition to the answer, it's worth mentioning that I resolved this by forming the following expression instead:

```
^(?:\s*(exclude|include|hide|show|protect|risk|dir-merge|merge),\s*([-+HSPR:.])\s*(\S+)|\s*,?\s*([-+HSPR:.])\s*(\S+)|\s*(exclude|include|hide|show|protect|risk|dir-merge|merge)\s*(\S+))$
```

The minor difference being the transition from `(-|+|H|S|P|R|:|.)` to `([-+HSPR:.])`.  The square parenthesis have the effect of escaping the characters, preventing the `|+` expression matching `nothing`.

Comment: `.` in `(-|+|H|S|P|R|:|.)` matches any character. That's can't be what you intended, you need to escape it. It would be better to write that as `[-+HSPR:.]`. Also, why do you have two sets of parentheses around these groups?

Comment: Could you show us the errors that you're getting for what looks like a perfectly cromulent regex?

Comment: Hadn't actually noticed the double of parens, I will adjust it.  Not that it will make a difference.

Comment: The error is: `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat`

Comment: That said, it seems that switching the code generation to use a ([.....]) format for the single character matches is now producing a different error.  I'll see if I can address this before seeing if the existing error remains...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have more than one problem here.  The "nothing to repeat" can be reproduced very easily:

```
>>> re.compile("|+")
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

`+` means "match one or more of the preceding", but an empty string precedes `+`.  You probably mean to say `\+` in a couple places instead of plain `+`.

Comment: Indeed you are right.  I had overlooked the single character group.  Since updating it to include `[]` parens and removing the '|` separator, it seems to compile.